# Can a non dividend-paying product (say ETF) suddenly start paying dividends?

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, dividends

If I buy shares of a product that currently does not pay dividends, can it theoretically/technically start paying dividends in the future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Consider Microsoft,

> Updated Jan. 17, 2003 11:59 p.m. ET
>
> Software giant Microsoft Corp.,
>   finally bowing to mounting pressure to return some of its huge cash
>   hoard to investors, said it will begin paying a regular annual
>   dividend to shareholders.

From [Wall Street Journal](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB1042311223645379424). Thus, for the years prior to 2003, the company didn't pay dividends but changed that.

---

There can also be some special one-time dividends as Microsoft did the following year according to the [Wall Street Journal](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB109035431245368850):

> The $32 billion one-time dividend payment, which comes to $3 for each
>   share of Microsoft stock, could be a measurable stimulus to the U.S.
>   economy -- and is expected to arrive just in time for holiday
>   shopping.

Course companies can also reduce to stop dividends as well.

Comment: Although beyond the scope of the question: Conversely, a stock that has traditionally paid dividends can stop at any time.